# Android edit-text styling

Tags: android, styles, android-edittext

i'm new to android programming, i've styled buttons and textfield in web application using stylesheet, how can we do that in andoid, can anyone please tell me how to create a edittext like as shown below image in android.

how can we style a edittext in android.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use a Image as background for EditText. I don't believe this can be done in XML.

Comment: Please elaborate your requirement.